# eBay LMS SoldReport Date Range?

Tags: php, ebay-api, ebay-lms

I am using devbay's eBay SDK for PHP.

By default [SoldReport](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchant-data/CallRef/SoldReport.html) is returning the last 30 days.

I'm trying to filter the date range to specify one-day/24 hour period.

I'm assuming I need to include a date range filter somewhere in the StartDownloadJobRequest call.

```
$startDownloadJobRequest = new BulkDataExchange\Types\StartDownloadJobRequest();
$startDownloadJobRequest->downloadJobType = 'SoldReport';
$startDownloadJobRequest->UUID = uniqid();
$startDownloadJobRequest->downloadRequestFilter = new BulkDataExchange\Types\DownloadRequestFilter();
$startDownloadJobRequest->downloadRequestFilter->activeInventoryReportFilter = $activeInventoryReportFilter;
```

I tried `CreateTimeFrom` and `CreateTimeTo` but received an `Unknown property CreateTimeFrom error`, so I do not believe I can use that for this request.

Anyone know how to filter date range in reports?

edit:

So it looks like `startTime` and `endTime` is apart of `DownloadRequestFilter`
[DownloadRequestFilter](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/bulk-data-exchange/CallRef/types/DownloadRequestFilter.html) [DateTime](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/bulk-data-exchange/CallRef/types/DateFilter.html)

I thought something like this would work..

```
$datefilter = new BulkDataExchange\Types\DateFilter();
$datefilter->startTime = new DateTime('22-10-2016');
$datefilter->endTime = new DateTime('23-10-2016');
//
$startDownloadJobRequest->downloadRequestFilter->dateFilter = $datefilter;
```

but this doesn't work and I still get all results.